# How to delete rows of dependent tables

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, database-design

I am new in database and in my application i want when i delete any project then deleted all tasks related to this project.Following is my table structure.I want to use this query in php.
please help.Thanks in Advanced.

```
 Table:- Project
         -Project_ID (primary)
         -ProjectName

 Table:- Task
        -Task_ID ( primary)
        -project_ID
        -TaskName
```

Comment: Thanks Tommy:- Please Give me proper link

Comment: Link fixed in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

referential integrity. check this [web](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

This is the concept you are looking for "ON DELETE CASCADE".

Comment: Thanks Tommy:- Please Give me proper link

Answer (score 0):

You can design this in database itself ... It will delete in automatically

```
 ALTER TABLE `Task` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `project_ID` ) REFERENCES `Project`.`project_ID` (
`project_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

Answer (score 0):

first delete the records from table `Task`

then you can delete the records of table `Project`

**example**

suppose you want to delete the record from table `Project` which have `Project_Id=3`

do this in two steps

1. delete records from table `Task` which has foreign key of Porject_ID

   **DELETE FROM `Task` WHERE Project_Id=3**
2. then you can delete the record from table `Project`

   **DELETE FROM `Project` WHERE Project_Id=3**

Comment: Thanks Satish: But if i have more than one tasks then how i can use that query